# snmpwalk doesnt work on net-snmp altho snmpget works

Tags: networking, net-snmp

I am trying to monitor a system with net-snmp, and I am using my own MIB.
i added the needed files in the path and **snmpget works**

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public IP MY-MIB::myField.0
```

the thing is that when i run snmpwalk it doesnt show the results in the output.
I tried:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public IP -m MY-MIB
```

> Of course i run it with the IP of the machine i want to probe

i also tried adding MY-MIB to **MIBS** and then export it.
but it still doesnt appear in the log.

thanks in advance.